# script for checking IP's hostname from file

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I  used for to file one contain the IP with hostname  like the /ec/hosts
 and the other contain the IP and counter try to print the ip if hostname not found and if is found print the hostname.

Script:

```
for i in `cat ip | awk '{print $2}'` ;do
   var=`grep "$i" Server_ip` |
   awk ' {if($var == "") print $i  else print $1}';
done
```

File 1

```
localhost 127.0.0.1
test 10.0.0.1
test1 10.0.0.2
```

File 2

```
3 127.0.0.1
2 10.0.0.1
1 10.0.0.2
4 10.0.0.3
5 10.0.0.4
```

Desired output

```
localhost
test
test1
10.0.0.3
10.0.0.4
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? If your script is not doing the right thing then please state clearly the expected output and the actual output.

Comment: The if condition is not working as I am trying the fetch the data from Server_ip file and incase the ip not found want to print the ip

Comment: "not working" is never a good description of the behaviour. Please state clearly the exact test input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: First I compare IP from file 2 with file1 if the ip found in file 1 then print hostname else print  ip

Comment: Show test input, expected output and actual output of your script. Is it really that hard to understand??

Comment: Like Kaylum I don't understand why you're doing what you're doing, but I can tell you that you can't use $i and $var inside the awk statement.  You need something like awk -v var=$var -v i=$i  '{if(var == ""){ print i}  else { print $1}}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this;

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat ip | awk '{print $2}'` ;do
var=`awk -v ip=${i} '$2 == ip {print $1}' Server_ip`

 if [ -z "$var" ]; then
  echo $i
 else 
  echo "$var"
 fi

done
```

Eg;

```
user@host:/tmp/test$ cat Server_ip
localhost 127.0.0.1
test 10.0.0.1
test1 10.0.0.2

user@host:/tmp/test$ cat ip
3 127.0.0.1
2 10.0.0.1
1 10.0.0.2
4 10.0.0.3
5 10.0.0.4

user@host:/tmp/test$ ./test.sh
localhost
test
test1
10.0.0.3
10.0.0.4
```